# How to center two divs side by side?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, center

I am using bootstrap and I have two container inside a bootstrap container. Like this:

```
        <div class="container">
            <div id="container-map">
                aasdasd
            </div>
            <div id="container-buttons">
                asdasda
            </div>
        </div>
```

What I am trying to do is center the two divs, **#container-map** and **#container-buttons** side by side, inside the main container.

This is my custom CSS for the two divs:

```
#container-map,
#container-buttons {
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
}
```

Comment: try adding... float: left;

Comment: @Aaron float doesn't allow to center ....

Comment: Use `text-align: center` on `.container`

Comment: possible duplicate of [centering two divs within one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246079/centering-two-divs-within-one)

Comment: It works if I add it directly to the html using the style property, but if I write it in my custom CSS external file, it refuses to work...

Comment: Maybe some Bootstrap's rules override code in your CSS file. Did you put Bootstrap stylesheet **before** your custom stylesheet in HTML?

Comment: inspect the element (right click on element and choose inspect element from the menu).  There must be some other style overwriting the one that you are using in yur stylesheet

Comment: I managed to achieve the samething using the external file. I did use the correct order to the external files as well. And I couldn't find anything overwriting the property.

The problem now is that they are horizontally aligned, but rather vertically (one above the other).

Comment: Well, it seems to work now, after I changed some things. The problem is that there is a small gap between the two divs now... and it's not the margin.

Comment: Remove spaces in your HTML code between inline-blocks

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/otbmuwvx/

Answer (score 1):

Is there a reason you don't want to use the bootstraps built in gridsystem?  Something like this?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3 col-md-offset-3">
            <div class="container-map">
                asdf
            </div>
         </div>
         <div class="col-md-3">
             <div class="container-buttons">
                  asdf
              </div>
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Yes. The content is not static, so the size will be changing all the time. And I want them to be aligned side by side. I wasn't able to achieve that using the grid system.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your CSS to this

```
#container-map,
#container-buttons {
   float: left;
   margin-left: auto;
}
```

Both containers will be centered and side by side

Answer (score 0):

You can try the code from this example (using `text-align: center;` on .container `display:inline-block;` for divs).

```
<style>
.container {
  position:relative;
  text-align:center;
}
#dv1, #dv2 {
  display:inline-block;
  width:100px;
  margin:0 3px;
  background:#33f;
}
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div id="dv1">Div 1</div>
  <div id="dv2">Div 2</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you make both your divs to take equal height using [flex](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex/). You can refer the link to find out the browsers which support it. Have a look at this:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  width: 400px;
  background: #eee;
}

.column {
  flex: 1;
  background: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  margin: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="column">
    <p>aasdasd</p>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <p>asdasda</p>
    <p>asdasda</p>
  </div>
</div>
```